# Are Runway Profile Descent charts available to non-121 carriers? If so, where can I find them?

Tags: instrument-procedures, efficiency, fuel-consumption, descent

[AIM 5-4-2(c)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_4.html) says:

> When crossing altitudes and speed restrictions are issued verbally or are depicted on a chart, ATC will expect the pilot to descend first to the crossing altitude and then reduce speed. Verbal clearances for descent will normally permit an uninterrupted descent in accordance with the procedure as described in paragraph b above. Acceptance of a charted fuel efficient descent (Runway Profile Descent) clearance requires the pilot to adhere to the altitudes, speeds, and headings depicted on the charts unless otherwise instructed by ATC. PILOTS RECEIVING A CLEARANCE FOR A FUEL EFFICIENT DESCENT ARE EXPECTED TO ADVISE ATC IF THEY DO NOT HAVE RUNWAY PROFILE DESCENT CHARTS PUBLISHED FOR THAT AIRPORT OR ARE UNABLE TO COMPLY WITH THE CLEARANCE

I'm interested in learning more about these charted descents.  Are these charts publicly available, or are they proprietary to particular carriers (similar to how certain carriers have self-created instrument approaches that only they are approved to fly)?

If they are publicly available, where can I find examples?